# Lua/Love2D Resource Loader (Queue)

Tags: lua, lua-table

I made this resource queue in Love2D.

```
function GameState:queue(file, arg)
    self.res.loaded = self.res.loaded + 1;
    self.res.queue[self.res.loaded] = {f = file, t = game.getResourceType(file), id = self.res.loaded, s = arg};
    game.log("Resource Queued: "..file);
    return {f = self.res.loaded, t = game.getResourceType(file), id = self.res.loaded, s = arg};
end

function GameState:loadQueue(loader, post)
    self.post = post or function() self.state = self.prevState end;

    game.log("Loading Resource Queue...");

    queueThread = love.thread.newThread("queue.lua");
    queueChannel = love.thread.getChannel("queue");

    local fonts = {};

    for k, v in pairs(self.res.queue) do
        if (not v or not v.f or not v.t) then goto continue end;
        if (v.t ~= self.RESOURCE_FONT) then
            queueChannel:push(v);
        else
            fonts[k] = v;
        end
        ::continue::
    end

    for k, v in pairs(fonts) do
        self.res.fnt[k] = love.graphics.newFont(v.f, v.s);
        print("Loaded Resource: "..v.f);
    end

    queueChannel:push(table.size(self.res.queue)-table.size(fonts));

    if (table.size(self.res.queue)-table.size(fonts) > 0) then
        queueThread:start();
    else
        queueChannel = nil;
        queueThread = nil;
        return;
    end

    self.state = self.STATE_LOADING
end
```

The thread:

```
require "love.image"
require "love.audio"
require "love.sound"
require "love.timer"

queue = {};
img = {};
snd = {};
local queueChannel = love.thread.getChannel("queue");

local pop = queueChannel:pop();

while (type(pop) ~= "number" and pop) do
    queue[pop.id] = pop;
    pop = queueChannel:pop();
end

for k, v in pairs(queue) do
    if (not v or not v.f or not v.t) then print("Resource Load Failed!"); goto continue; end;

    if (v.t == 0) then -- image
        img[k] = love.image.newImageData(v.f);
        queueChannel:supply({data = img[k], t = 0, id = k, s = v.s});
    end
    if (v.t == 1) then -- sound
        snd[k] = love.audio.newSource(v.f, "static");
        queueChannel:supply({data = snd[k], t = 1, id = k, s = v.s});
    end
    ::continue::
    queue[k] = nil;
    print("Loaded Resource: "..v.f);
    love.timer.sleep(0.01);
end

queueChannel:clear();
queueChannel:push(true);

return;
```

Handling while loading resources:

```
if (self.state == self.STATE_LOADING) then
    local e = queueThread:getError();
    if (e ~= nil) then
        print("Thread: "..e)
    end

    local r = queueChannel:peek();
    if (type(r) == "table" and r and r.data and r.t) then
        if (r.t == self.RESOURCE_IMAGE) then
            if (r.s) then
                love.graphics.setDefaultFilter(r.s, r.s);
            end
            self.res.img[r.id] = love.graphics.newImage(r.data);
        end
        if (r.t == self.RESOURCE_SOUND) then
            self.res.snd[r.id] = r.data;
        end
        queueChannel:pop();
    end

    if (queueChannel:peek() == true and type(queueChannel:peek()) == "boolean") then
        self.post();
        game.log("Finished Loading Resources.");
    end
end
```

If there's any bad habits, or anything that could be improved, please let me know.

Comment: 1. `goto` is evil. 2. Use better variable names than `e` or `r`.

Comment: I disagree. It's legitimate to use `goto` in some cases, for instance when jumping to a point within the same function `goto` is being used. `goto` is used a lot in huge codebases such as the Linux kernel. This _goto is evil_ thing is cargocult originated by Dijkstra's infamous article _Goto statement considered harmful_. In this particular case, `goto` is well used. It's the recommended way of implementing `continue` in Lua, as the language lacks a native `continue` statement.

Answer (score 1):

In Lua, it's not necessary to separate statements by a semicolon (it's not even necessary to do it when writting several statements in the same line). However it's possible to do it.

In this snippet:

> ```
> for k, v in pairs(self.res.queue) do
>     if (not v or not v.f or not v.t) then goto continue end;
>     if (v.t ~= self.RESOURCE_FONT) then
>         queueChannel:push(v);
>     else
>         fonts[k] = v;
>     end
>     ::continue::
> end
> ```

You're using `pairs` in several parts of the code to iterate tables which are actually arrays. Variable `self.res.queue` is an array since:

> ```
> function GameState:queue(file, arg)
>     self.res.loaded = self.res.loaded + 1;
>     self.res.queue[self.res.loaded] = <object>;
> end
> ```

In the cases a table is actually an array is preferred to use `ipairs` because is way more faster than `pairs`. In addition to that, it tells other people reading the code the table is actually an array (which is a valuable hint in a dynamic language such as Lua).

At the bottom of `GameState:loadQueue`:

> ```
> if (table.size(self.res.queue)-table.size(fonts) > 0) then
>     queueThread:start(); else
>     queueChannel = nil;
>     queueThread = nil;
>     return;
> end
>
> self.state = self.STATE_LOADING
> ```

The `return` statement in the else branch can be removed if you move `self.state` up to the then branch. The semantics hold as either `queueThread:start()` or not.

```
if (table.size(self.res.queue)-table.size(fonts) > 0) then
    self.state = self.STATE_LOADING;
    queueThread:start();
else
    queueChannel = nil;
    queueThread = nil;
    return;
end
```